# When randomly determining a town's magic items, are items like scrolls and potions hand picked?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The tables seem to only state the level of the spell and the caster level so I'm guessing the GM picks the actual spell based on those results?

Comment: In D&D 3.5 the DMG has tables for (e.g.) scroll contents on p. 239. Did Paizo not include such a thing in the Pathfinder books? I'd be surprised if so, since they're in the d20 SRD too, as OGL content... Though, I notice they're [missing from the PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls), so maybe.

Comment: http://donjon.bin.sh/pathfinder/magic/shop.html Is my preferred source of generation, might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic item availability is not specified by the rules, it is left entirely up to the GM. However you can draw at least some level of guidance from the Ultimate Equipment treasure generation rules, which make the distinction between common and uncommon scrolls/potions and give their probabilities. You could even use the treasure generation rules there to randomly generate a shop's contents.

There's an online generator using the rules in Ultimate Equipment [here,](http://d20gen.net) but it is intended for determining the treasure for defeating certain types of monsters, not filling out shops. Still, you might find some combination of inputs that gives you good results.

Full disclosure: I am the creator of the online generator.